# webservice CopyIntoItems is not working to upload file to sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-services

The following piece of C# is always failing with

1

Unknown

Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Anybody some idea what i am missing?

```
        try
        {
            //Copy WebService Settings                
            String strUserName = "abc";
            String strPassword = "abc";
            String strDomain = "SVR03";
            String FileName = "Filename.xls";

            WebReference.Copy copyService = new WebReference.Copy();
            copyService.Url = "http://192.168.11.253/_vti_bin/copy.asmx";
            copyService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential
                                          (strUserName,
                                           strPassword,
                                           strDomain);


            // Filestream of attachment
            FileStream MyFile = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\28200.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            // Read the attachment in to a variable
            byte[] Contents = new byte[MyFile.Length];
            MyFile.Read(Contents, 0, (int)MyFile.Length);
            MyFile.Close();

            //Change file name if not exist then create new one                
            String[] destinationUrl = { "http://192.168.11.253/Shared Documents/28200.xls" };

            // Setup some SharePoint metadata fields
            WebReference.FieldInformation fieldInfo = new WebReference.FieldInformation();
            WebReference.FieldInformation[] ListFields = { fieldInfo };

            //Copy the document from Local to SharePoint
            WebReference.CopyResult[] result;
            uint NewListId = copyService.CopyIntoItems
                (FileName,
                 destinationUrl,
                 ListFields, Contents, out result);
            if (result.Length < 1)
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to create a document library item");
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine( result.Length );    
                Console.WriteLine( result[0].ErrorCode );
                Console.WriteLine( result[0].ErrorMessage );
                Console.WriteLine( result[0].DestinationUrl);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: you should debug some. which object is getting null?

Comment: Does this behaviour occure only if there is already an Document called like the one you want to upload on the server?

Answer (score 1):

If you will use instead the IP address (http://192.168.11.253) the server name (http://...) this web service works well.

Answer (score 0):

Without understanding more about your specific error, I too would be grasping at straws.  It looks like your `destinationUrl` is an incomplete path.  You typically need to specify the entire URL to a site or site collection.  So, I would expect your `destinationUrl` to be something like `http://192.168.11.253/[SiteName]/Shared Documents/28200.xls` instead of `http://192.168.11.253/Shared Documents/28200.xls"`.